# Rspec test failures due to load order of engines in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-engines

I have a rails app with multiple engines mounted to it. 
Here is the method responsible to load engines:

```
def self.engines
  @@engines ||= Dir['%s/*' % ENGINES_DIRECTORY].
  select { |entry| File.directory? entry }.
  map { |entry| File.basename entry }.
  map { |entry| Engine.new entry }.
  select { |engine| engine.active? }
end
```

Where `engine.active?` depends on environment variable to load a particular engine in production and pre-prod environments. Each engine is for a particular client and only that engine is loaded on a dedicated server.  But the problem is with RSpec, as all the engines are loaded and the locale files of the engine that is loaded last is what get tested and all `I18n` related tests fail if `en.yml` files are not same for all engines.

Note: The folder structure for rspec:

```
 spec:
    :engine1
      - engine1 related tests
    :engine 2 
      - engine2 related tests
    :engine3
      - engine3 related tests
```

Please let me know if you have dealt with this problem or you can suggest a solution. Would really appreciate your help.